# Cannot install Jenkins: no valid crumb

Tags: nginx, jenkins, google-compute-engine

I've just installed Jenkins on a google cloud vm and configured nginx to point at 8080. I can enter the initial admin password and then i get to the screen where i can select plugins. When i click on "install suggested plugins" an error appears:

```
No valid crumb was included in this request
```

I started Jenkins with the command:

```
java -Dhudson.security.csrf.requestfield=Jenkins-Crumb -jar jenkins.war
```

stdout says:

```
INFO: Session node016ikde2z4paqem02o7wos0rgd1 already being invalidated
Nov 02, 2017 7:57:44 PM hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter doFilter
WARNING: Found invalid crumb 27d19a27be31d1d5703128b635b60c3b.  Will 
check remaining parameters for a valid one...
Nov 02, 2017 7:57:44 PM hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter doFilter
WARNING: No valid crumb was included in request for 
/pluginManager/installPlugins. Returning 403.
```

does anybody know how i can either disable CSRF or include a valid crumb in my request? I can generate a valid crumb by running:

```
$ curl -u "admin:ebdcf2fcf6f74ee8b4ec907a1486ml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)'
Jenkins-Crumb:ef6250c9afe294555e20f1b9ab875261
```

but i don't know what to do with it after that.

Many thanks!

Comment: which jenkins version are u using?

Answer (score 0):

To Disable CSRF (although this is not recommended), follow the below 3 steps:

- Log in to Jenkins as an Administrator
- GOTO: Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security and enable Prevent
  Cross Site Request Forgery exploits
- Uncheck this option

---

Mention the version of the Jenkins you are using to suggest on how to provide a valid crumb in your request.